# How to put jars from all subprojects into one directory in gradle 4.0?

Tags: gradle

I have a multi project project build as follows and when I do gradle clean build it creates jars under build/libs/ of each sub directory like below

```
root
   /projectA
       /build/libs/projectA.jar
   /projectB
       /build/libs/projectB.jar
```

Now I want to have all these subprojects jars (project A & B) in one place (say root/build/libs) so it would like this

```
root
   /build
       /libs
           /projectA.jar
           /projectB.jar
   /projectA
       /build/libs/projectA.jar
   /projectB
       /build/libs/projectB.jar
```

How do I do this ? Any code example? I am using gradle 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, albeit its rough, because hardcoding subprojects is not ideal.

```
task copyJars(type: Copy) {
    def jars = [
        '/projectA/build/libs/.', 
        '/projectB/build/libs/.']
    from jars
    include '*.jar'
    into 'build/libs'
}
```